# Issue with for cycle in django and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I used django to try and make a replay of comments due their IDs. Everything is working, but I can only get the last item from for cycle via javascript.

```
{% for comment in object_comments %}
   <li>
      <article>
         <div class="comment-avatar">
            <img src="images/blog/author.png" class="avatar">
               <span class="comment-reply">
                  <a id='reply' class="comment-reply-link" onClick="a_onClick()">Reply</a>
               </span>
         </div>

         <script>
            function button_onClick() {
               $('').click();
            }
            function a_onClick() {
               window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);

               document.getElementById('text').value = "{{comment.name}}";
            }
         </script>

         <div class="comment-body">
            <div class="meta-data">
               <a href="#" class="comment-author">{{ comment.name }}</a>
               <span class="comment-date">
                  {{ comment.pub_date }}
               </span>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-content">
               {{ comment.text }}
            </div>
         </div>
      </article>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The data is analyzed by `document.getElementById('text').value =  {{comment.name}};`

Can someone help find some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you’re only getting the last value is that your `<script>` function is inside the for loop, and so the code your Django loop is outputting contains this script code n number of times, *using the same function name each time*. So each definition “overwrites”, i.e. replaces, the previous one. So the only definition of `a_onClick()` that the browser’s Javascript interpreter uses is the one for the final iteration of the loop, with the final `{{ comment }}` in the loop.

Your snippet doesn't include the `#text` element that the function changes, so I can't follow it completely. But to prevent the error you’ve described, first of all move your `<script>` code outside the Django for-loop - place it after the loop instead, or at the end of the document body. Then your function calls need to pass the correct `comment.name` for each item in the loop. You could do this inside the loop with:

```
onclick="a_onClick('{{ comment.name }}')";
```

and then change your function to this:

```
function a_onClick(comment_name) {
  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
  document.getElementById('text').value = comment_name;
}
```

Comment: You're brilliant! Thank you so much! ++++